# I need create a slider with react js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

[image]

My design this but I don't know How to do this steps

I trying different config with swiper and slick slides
[image]
My code like this but

[image]
that is my result

Comment: Would you post your code in text format?

Answer (score 0):

At the left and right of the container you can add opacity or blur or gradient with opacity using `::after` and `::before` pseudo selectors.

Answer (score 0):

This effect not related to **Swiper API** (It is some `transparent edges` of `.swiper`).

The most simple way is to add [css mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask).

```
.swiper {
  /* MASK */
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 80%, transparent 100%)
}
```

**Better to disable on mobile by media query.

### Demo:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  slidesPerView: 4,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  mousewheel: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  loop: true,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: lightblue;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  /* MASK */
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 80%, transparent 100%)
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10.3.1/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Swiper -->
<main class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div> 
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</main>

</script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10.3.1/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```